# How to completely remove sound strips from blender file?

Tags: rendering, audio

I kept wondering how to remove all sound strips/file from blender file. At first, RebusRender would say that my sound files had unsupporting characters. I changed the names of the sound files, assuming characters meant names. Then Blender never updated the names. I deleted the sound strips from the animation, but they still appear with an error "File not found: sound_title". [image]

Comment: "Then Blender never updated the names" seems to be the only issue related to Blender itself here, but you should explain perhaps _how_ you tried to rename them. Other thant this, maybe the renderfarm plugin could be not updating a remote file, maybe? You can try opening a new default file, and trying to import those renamed sounds from the above file, so that you can check their real name in Blender.

Comment: Oh right, my bad. The only way I know of renaming the sound files (well I thought it was the only way) was renaming it in the standard window file folder I found it in.